# How iterate through every possible combination of X and Y

Tags: c#, java, for-loop, iterator

I'm trying to iterate through all combinations of X and Y. I'm incrementing the value by 0.01, which is a double, but it never actually hits 0.

```
for (double x = -50; x < 50; x += 0.01)
{
     for (double y = -50; y <50; y += 0.01)
     {
          //Some code
     }
}
```

Any idea why this happens? I'm assuming it's something to do with 'double', if so, what can I use as an alternative?

Update: I changed it to decimal and changed all the decimal numbers to have an 'm' on the end. It all works fine now, I love you guys :D

The code now reads -

```
for (decimal x = -50; x < 50; x += 0.01m)
{
      for (decimal y = -50; y < 50; y += 0.01m)
      {
            // Some code
      }
}
```

Comment: Use decimal instead of double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to rounding/truncation errors, it's impossible to store the value 0.01 exactly in a double. As such, adding several of them together increases the magnitude of the error, potentially making it miss 0. Instead, try the decimal type or iterate over ints.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are testing for zero something like this:

```
if (x == 0.0) {
    // it is zero.
}
```

That is likely to fail due to *floating point rounding error*.

One of the properties of floating point numbers is that they don't have exact representations for a lot of decimal numbers.  In this case, you will find that the closest representation for 0.01 is a "off" by a tiny amount.  So when you add `0.01` to `-50.0` five thousand times, the result is not exactly `0.0`.

You need to test whether `x` is zero plus/minus some small error; e.g. `0.00001` should be OK in this case.

Better still you can avoid the whole issue of rounding by declaring the loop variables as integers and then dividing that by 0.01 to give your `x` and `y` values; e.g.

```
for (int i = -5000; i < 5000; i++) {
    double x = i / 0.01d;
    // etcetera
```

---

In fact, since your code is using a `0.01` rather than `0.01d`, I think that the error in the representation is going to be more than it ought to be ...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is floating point numbers in computer can generally not exactly represent decimal values, they only approximate them. You can check the wiki articel about [floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) for more details.

The code you have works better if you use something like this:

```
for (int idxX = -5000; idxX < 5000; idxX += 1)
{
    double x = (double) idxX / 100.0;

    for (int idxY = -5000; idxY < 5000; idxY += 1)
    {
        double y = (double) idxY / 100.0;

        //Some code
    }
}
```

This avoid some of the problems of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

try this trick:

```
for (int x = -5000; x < 5000; x++)
    {
         for (int y = -5000; y <5000; y++)
         {
              System.out.println((double)x/100.0+" ~~ "+(double)y/100.0);
         }
    }
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Use decimal instead. Then you will hit 0. Calculating with double will give you rounding errors

Answer (score 0):

In most C-derived languages, `double` and `float` are numbers with a base-2 [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). This means that it has very little relation to decimal numbers per se, and cannot necessarily always store them exactly, it just stores an approximation.

The solution to this would be to use a base-10 power, and, luckily, C# has a type with this property: `decimal`. Replace `double` with `decimal` and you're probably good to go.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if (x == (.01-.01)){}
```

Comment: Care to explain? Also, mind the parentheses. They're not matching up.